# How to get the date of Monday and Friday of last week?

Tags: google-sheets

What is the formula to return the dates of Monday and Friday of last week.

I am posting this on Tuesday, June 5, 2018.  I am looking for formulas that will return 5/28/2018 and 6/1/2018.

Answer (score 3):

```
=A1-WEEKDAY(A1)-1
=A1-WEEKDAY(A1)-5
```

---

- [WEEKDAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092985)
- A1:`=TODAY()`